# Include a form from Salesforce Marketing Cloud on site via <embed>, <object>, or <iframe>?

Tags: forms, object, iframe, embed, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I need to include forms created in Salesforce Marketing Cloud onto a separate site. Between embed, object, or iframe... which approach is best for this type of media (form with confirmation)?  Which approach is best for accessibility and control of responsive design?